# Can't access variables that have been changed inside a function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to return a variable that has been changed inside a function for use outside of the function. I know the scope is only within the function so declared the variables outside of the function first, therefore I am only reassigning them. However I cannot get them to to be returned for use in the main block of code.

```js
let computerChoice = ""
let playerChoice = ""
gameChoices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]

/* Get the computers choice for the play*/
function getComputerChoice() {
  let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  let computerChoice = gameChoices[randomNumber];
  console.log(computerChoice);
  return (computerChoice);
}

/* Get the players choice for the play*/
function getPlayerChoice() {
  let playerChoice = prompt("Do you choose Rock, Paper or Scissors?").toLowerCase();
  return (playerChoice);
}

getComputerChoice()
console.log(computerChoice)
getPlayerChoice()
```

Comment: You _can_ access it, you just choose not to. You don't assign the returned value from _either_ `get...` function call - compare them with your calls to `Math.floor` and `prompt`, for example.

Comment: "However I cannot get them to to be returned for use in the main block of code." << They are returned, you just throw them away immediately after they are returned, because you don't assign them anywhere.

Comment: There's a bit of confusion here regarding your use of the 'global' variables, and redefining them within the functions. A far better approach is to avoid globals at all, if possible, and have your functions create and return the values which you then assign within the scope they will be used in. Here's a refactored version of your logic displaying this pattern. I've linked to it in jsFiddle as it seems some people got too trigger happy with the close button: https://jsfiddle.net/bna78p3y/

Answer (score -1):

Only add `let` when you are declaring it. You should omit it when editing it's value:

```
  ...
  computerChoice = gameChoices[randomNumber];
  ...
  playerChoice = prompt("Do you choose Rock, Paper or Scissors?").toLowerCase();
  ...
```